# Erro ao abrir o datapicker bootstrap

Tags: jquery

Compramos recentemente um template de um determinado site e entre suas funcionalidades, vem o datapicker bootstrap conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só quero usar apenas essa linha:

```
<div class="form-control-wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="date" class="form-control floating-label" placeholder="Date">
</div>
```

O problema é que quando vou retirar as linhas abaixo que não farão parte do projeto:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header"><h5 class="card-header-text">Raised Button</h5></div>
                         <div class="card-block">
                             <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xl-4">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-dynamic-default" checked />
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-dynamic-primary" checked />
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" checked />
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-dynamic-warning" checked />
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-dynamic-danger" checked />
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-dynamic-info" checked />
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-dynamic-secondary" checked />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xl-4">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-dynamic-sm" checked />
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" checked />
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-dynamic-lg" checked />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xl-4">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-dynamic-state" checked />
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light js-dynamic-disable m-l-20 m-r-10">Disable</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light m-r-30 js-dynamic-enable">Enable</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Ele para de funcionar. Não sei se existe alguma referência. Enfim, qualquer linha que eu tire, ele para de funcionar. Enxuguei o máximo que pude no código e parei dessa forma: Vejam:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Able Pro Responsive Bootstrap 4 Admin Template by Phoenixcoded</title>
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE9 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="description" content="Phoenixcoded">
    <meta name="keywords" content=", Responsive, Landing, Bootstrap, App, Template, Mobile, iOS, Android, apple, creative app">
    <meta name="author" content="Phoenixcoded">

    <!-- Favicon icon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

    <!-- Google font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- iconfont -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/icon/icofont/css/icofont.css">

    <!-- simple line icon -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/icon/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css">

    <!-- Required Fremwork -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Date Picker css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/datepicker/css/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.css" />

    <!-- Style.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/responsive.css"> 

    <!--color css-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/color/color-1.css" id="color"/>

</head>

<body class="horizontal-fixed fixed">
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar chat end-->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Container-fluid starts -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header"><h5 class="card-header-text">Raised Button</h5></div>
                         <div class="card-block">
                             <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xl-4">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-dynamic-default" checked />
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-dynamic-primary" checked />
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" checked />
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-dynamic-warning" checked />
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-dynamic-danger" checked />
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-dynamic-info" checked />
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-dynamic-secondary" checked />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xl-4">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-dynamic-sm" checked />
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" checked />
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-dynamic-lg" checked />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xl-4">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-dynamic-state" checked />
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light js-dynamic-disable m-l-20 m-r-10">Disable</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light m-r-30 js-dynamic-enable">Enable</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                        <!-- Row start -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h5 class="card-header-text">Date-Time Widgets</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <!-- Row start -->
                            <div class="row m-b-30 advance-elements">
                                <div class="col-xl-3">
                                    <!-- <h6 class="sub-title">Date Picker</h6> -->
                                    <!-- end of modal -->
                                    <div class="form-control-wrapper">
                                        <input type="text" id="date" class="form-control floating-label" placeholder="Date">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
        <!-- Required Jqurey -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/tether.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Required Fremwork -->
        <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Date picker.js -->
        <script src="assets/plugins/datepicker/js/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/plugins/datepicker/js/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js"></script>

        <!-- Select 2 js -->
        <script src="assets/plugins/select2/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Max-Length js -->
        <script src="assets/plugins/max-length/js/bootstrap-maxlength.js"></script>

        <!-- switchery js -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/switchery/js/switchery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Multi Select js -->
        <script src="assets/plugins/multi-select/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/plugins/multi-select/js/jquery.multi-select.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/multi-select/js/jquery.quicksearch.js"></script>

        <!-- Tags js -->
        <script src="assets/plugins/tags/js/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Datepicker js -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

        <!-- bootstrap range picker -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/daterangepicker.js"></script>

        <!-- custom js -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/pages/advance-form.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/menu-horizontal.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">SyntaxHighlighter.all();</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Alguém pode me orientar para identificar o que está causando esse conflito ou me indicar outro plugin que faça o mesmo efeito conforme a imagem?

Comment: Boa tarde. Por que vc quer retirar linhas do código?

Comment: Mas o que vc queria mudar? O que vc pretende?

Comment: Fiz um ajuste no post. Realmente havia ficado vago minha dúvida.

Comment: Complicado isso porque em alguma parte de um script desses pode estar usando o código que vc quer excluir... por exemplo, contando ou verificando um elemento desse código, e a outra parte do código depende disso... ou seja, se for vazio, o script causa erro. Se não encontrar uma solução, vai ter que apelar pra gambiarra, colocando `display: none` na div apenas para escondê-la da página.

Comment: Olá dvd. Fiz conforme sugeriu e funcionou. Obrigado mais uma vez.

Answer (score 0):

Se vc esta querendo uma coisa simples, mas que funcione, utilize o plugin do jQuery, tem como estiliza-lo também. [veja mais aqui](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: Olá Leandro. Na verdade gostaria de usar conforme a imagem. Fiz como o dvd sugeriu e funcionou. Obrigado.